# removing diffgram from .net web service returning dataset

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-3.5

per my client request I have been requested to return a dataset. basically it's an arraylist that i convert to dataset as follow

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table");
 DataRow drow;
 tbl.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
 tbl.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
 foreach (NameIDPair item in AL)
        {
            drow = tbl.NewRow();
            drow["ID"] = item.ID;
            drow["Name"] = item.Name;
            tbl.Rows.Add(drow);
        }
 ds.Tables.Add(tbl);
```

the problem with my client is this web service add a diffgram like diffgr:hasChanges="iserted" tag to each row, and they're pretending is not consistent with other web services used by them. How can I remove this tag in the XML returned? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for inconveniences. I just Added tbl.AcceptChanges(); and the diffgram has been removed.